# Recover accidentally deleted configuration.nix file

Tags: nixos

Suppose there was a file `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` used for a `nixos-rebuild switch` process once. Suppose it was accidentally removed from a filesystem.

Is there a way to recover it somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the configuration option `system.copySystemConfiguration`:

> **system.copySystemConfiguration**
>   If enabled, copies the NixOS configuration file $NIXOS_CONFIG (usually /etc/nixos/configuration.nix) to the system
>   store path.
>
> Type:"boolean"
>
> Default:false
>
> Declared by:
>   `<nixpkgs/nixos/modules/system/activation/top-level.nix>`

If you enable this option, there should be a file `/run/current-system/configuration.nix` containing the configuration.nix for the current system (it also exists for any other system you built).